# The 'os' module in Python says "No such file or directory" even when there definitely is one

Tags: python, directory

I am trying to open an `.npy` file. However, Python keeps saying that there exists no such file or directory, even when there is one...

To make sure that it isn't an issue of giving correct path names, I changed my directory to the folder that contains the `.npy` file that I want. Then used `list.dir()` and used it to use `np.load` (the code is below):

```
os.chdir(filename_dir) #filename_dir is the directory I want to get to that contains the npy file I want)
the_path=os.path.join(os.getcwd()+os.listdir()[-1]) #i.e. I did this to make sure that the directory is correct
data=np.load(the_path)
```

However, I got the error, `[Errno 2] No such file or directory: .......`
The error occurs when I try `np.load`. I couldn't understand this because I explicitly made the path `the_path` from what Python says exists.

Comment: Did you try to print `the_path`? Is it absolute (`/home/user/directory`) or relative (`../directory`)?

Comment: I think it's abslute (`C:\Users\DELL\OneDrive - 성균관대학교\Cha's Lab\ITGAN&SCGL\Brain_Data(ROI)\abcd-timeseries-recent\abcd-fmriprep-rs-time\fmriprep-deri-NDARINV003RTV85\fmriprep\sub-NDARINV003RTV85\ses-baselineYear1Arm1\funcsub-NDARINV003RTV85_ses-baselineYear1Arm1_task-rest_run-4_space-MNIPediatricAsym_cohort-4_res-2_desc-preproc_atlas-harvardoxford_timeseries.npy`)

Comment: Not saying that this is the problem but maybe numpy has a problem with pathnames containing non-ascii characters (Korean?). You should be able to solve this by chdir() then use a relative filename

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Are you suggesting that I do something like, `np.load(os.listdir()[-1])`? (since I am already in the folder above my designated `.npy` I am trying to solve

Comment: I tried that put I still got an error `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'sub-NDARINV003RTV85_ses-baselineYear1Arm1_task-rest_run-4_space-MNIPediatricAsym_cohort-4_res-2_desc-preproc_atlas-harvardoxford_timeseries.npy'`

Comment: Is it possible that this error is caused because I sync the file to Onedrive? But even if so, wouldn't I not be able to see the file through `os.listdir()[-1]` either?

Comment: If you're in the right directory and you're getting a FileNotFound exception then my best guess now is that it's the 143 character filename that's causing the problem. Try renaming the file. Also, I'm intrigued to know what you think you're achieving by taking the last entry from the listdir list. Is that always going to be the file you want to process? Can you be certain?

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I'll try renaming the file manually to see if that works. Also, using the last entry from the listdir list was just done as an example. I wanted to make sure that the file actually shows up when I use listdir

Comment: OMG when I manually changed the file name, it worked! Thank yo uso much!! Unfortunately, unless I manually rename 40,000 flie names, I don't think I can do this because I can't access the files using the os module because it says "the file can't be found"... @JCaesar could you provide any solutions? (Also, if you want, you can post your comment as an answer and I'll mark it as an answer)

Comment: This looks like it's a Windows problem. I can create a file on macOS with **exactly** that name and I can perform whatever operations I like on it - e.g., os.path.getsize(), open()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the problem...

Windows (by default) has a maximum path length of 260 characters. The absolute path to this file exceeds that limit. The filename alone is 143 characters.

It looks as though even if you try to access the file using a relative path (i.e., chdir() to the appropriate folder then specify just the filename), numpy is probably working out the absolute path then failing.

You have said that renaming the file to something much shorter solves the problem but is impractical due to the high numbers of files that you need to process.

There is a Windows Registry key that can be modified to enable long pathnames: Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem\LongPathsEnabled

Changing that may help.

Or you could buy a Mac

Comment: Thank you for the answer! You said days worth of my time:)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `r`. For example,

```
file_path = r"filePath"
```

This may work...

Comment: OP doesn't have filePath as a string